# How to fix python3 on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

In attempt to remove an older version of python, I removed something important, and now nothing works.

```
> python3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/karm/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/home/karm/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f44dad8e740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

The output of `whereis python` is

```
python: /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3.8 /etc/python3.9 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.8 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python /home/karm/bin/python
```

When I run `export PYTHONHOME = /usr/` and `export PYTHONHOME = /usr/bin/python3.9`, the fields are fixed, but it doesn't work.

When I run `sudo apt install -f`, the output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 47.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3 amd64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 [47.6 kB]
Fetched 47.6 kB in 1s (77.5 kB/s) 
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It doesn't let me do anything. Is there a way to fix these issues without reinstalling the OS from boot drive?

Comment: Not really a programming question but rather one of system administration. Check on askubuntu.com how to reinstall a package and its dependencies. Just as a note though, Python is pretty fundamental to many Linux systems, so you may have to undo what you did manually, Reinstalling the OS may be the easier way for a beginner. Setting `PYTHONHOME` is probably not going to work, it shouldn't be needed at all.

Comment: Thanks, but literally nothing works :( . Not even `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3`.
I'll ask there too, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Were you trying to replace 3.8 with 3.9? Try to `sudo apt-get remove python3`, then fix broken and `install` again, but I'm really not sure that it will help. If you have `aptitude` installed, you can try to fix using it, sometimes it can resolve conflict which apt-get can't.

Comment: @SUTerliakov it doesn't let me even remove. I manually went and removed binaries (and probably not only) by `rm`. `aptitude` doesn't work as well. Maybe there is a place that I can find and download binaries directly? I googled for more than an hour, can't find anything.

Comment: Download sources, build and install to $HOME/python, sudo su, set PYTHONHOME, install with apt.

Comment: Or download ubuntu bootable thumb drive, boot, list files that belong to the python package, copy them to your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Python is not fully installed or removed. I never encountered this issue myself, but you might check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed) and see if this helps.

Comment: Didn't help :(
Thank you anyway.